# Tomcat (Host) Manager protection

Tags: security, tomcat

Are there any build in features that prohibit 
1) too many login attempts from the same IP
2) too many login attempts for the same username
or should I enhance those web applications by myself?
My server already got hacked once because I had a weak password, now I have a 10k bit keyfile for my piece of mind.
Those tomcat managers seem to be the next most dangerous things in my eyes, besides someone exploiting my web applications with malicious requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, the best would be to disable the Host manager if you don't need it, or restrict ONLY the manager app to a single IP address. As long as you have a strong password and a secure application you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You want the LockOutRealm:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/realm.html#LockOut_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm

It is configured by default in server.xml in remotely recent versions of Tomact 7 and all versions of Tomcat 8.